# Resizing textarea doesn't cover text

Tags: html, css

Here is a picture of the problem, when resizing the textarea, other table text elements are covering the textarea. I want it so that when you resize the textarea, it hides the text behind it so you can freely type & see everything in the textarea.

[image: Table Image]

EDIT: position: absolute covered the text, but now the textarea object of lower rows get in the way
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYiC4.png)
(don't downvote for linking image, stackoverflow won't let me post pictures because my rank isn't high enough)

Comment: You can use `position: absolute`!

Comment: Praveen it worked fine, answered my question. It doesn't work in your example (run snippet) but it works on my website, which is all that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `position: absolute` and wrap it inside a `position: relative` container.

```css
table {width: 100%;}
td {width: 33%;}
.wrap {position: relative; height: 100px; z-index: 2;}
.wrap textarea {position: absolute; height: 95px; width: 95%; z-index: 2;}
.wrap textarea:focus {z-index: 99;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrap"><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Hello World
      </td>
      <td>
        Hello World
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="wrap"><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Hello World
      </td>
      <td>
        Hello World
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```